# PMSM dynamic model

Tags: motor, modeling

I have been working on a dynamic model of the PMSM with surface mounted magnets and sinusoidal stator winding. I am little bit confused by formulas for the \$L_d\$ and \$L_q\$ inductances. I have found several formulas for these inductances and I don't know which of them are correct.

So I have attempted to derive the equations alone and I have followed these steps

**1. Formulas for magnetic fluxes for individual stator phases** (\$L\$ stator phase self inductance, \$M\$ mutual inductance for stator windings, \$\psi_m\$ magnetic flux of permanent magnet,\$\theta\$ rotor position i.e. angle between axes of stator phase \$a\$ and permanent magnet axes \$d\$)
 [image]

**2. Clarke transform** (\$\hat{a}=e^{j\frac{2\pi}{3}}\$)

[image]

**3. Magnetic fluxes in \$(\alpha,\beta)\$**

[image]

**4. Park transform**

[image]

**5. Magnetic fluxes in \$(d,q)\$**

[image]

Based on the formulas for magnetic fluxes in \$(d,q)\$ I have following formulas \$L_d=\frac{2}{3}(L-M)\$ and \$L_q=\frac{2}{3}(L-M)\$. Is my derivation correct? I am confused because my formulas are totally different from what I have seen so far. Thank you for any ideas.